# Error in deploying Google Earth Engine app in Heroku

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Earth Engine app in Heroku and streamlit. I have followed all the steps from this link [Deploying gee app in Streamlit](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap-streamlit). I also tried with service account. [Deploying gee app in Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsIjfD83ggA&t=668s). But there is error all the time.

> Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running
> earthengine authenticate in your command line, and then retry

This error raised in both place: streamlit and heroku. When I try with Earthengine token in streamlit this exception raised:

> File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/**init**.py",
> line 127, in Initialize
> credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials() File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 225,
> in get_persistent_credentials
> raise ee_exception.EEException(

But I can run GEE app in my local machine without having any kind of error by same token.